# What is the most efficient List-Type for Java parallelStream?

Tags: java, performance, list, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List<String> toProcess` which I want to process further with

```
toProcess.parallelStream().map(/*some function*/).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Which is the best List-type (like LinkedList, ArrayList ect.) for the initial list to gain the best speed from this multithreading?

*Additional information:* The expected element-count ranges in the size of 10^3-10^5, but the individual element can become quite big (10^5-10^6 chars).

---

Alternativly I can use `String[]` all over the place, as the amount of strings is guaranteed to not change (*results* will contain as many elements as *toProcess*).

---

Either way I have to iterate over all elements in order at the end. At the moment I use a `foreach`-loop to assemble the final result. This can be easily changed to a regular `for`-loop.

Comment: OT, but a nice read: http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-parallel-streams-are-bad-for-your-health/

Comment: @ThomasJunk Luckily the sole purpose of my programm is to apply a method to a bunch of strings and write the assembled output to a file. But thanks anyway, teaches me to handle Java-8 and WebApplications with care.

Comment: I would just pick any list and benchmark it, then try a few other kinds and see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are certain that the number of output elements equals the number of input elements, and you're satisfied with an array as the result, then definitely use `toArray` instead of a collector. If the pipeline has a fixed size throughout, the destination array will be preallocated with the right size, and the parallel operations deposit their results directly into the destination array at the right locations: no copying, reallocation, or merging.

If you want a `List`, you can always wrap the result using `Arrays.asList`, but of course you can't add or remove elements to the result.

**Collectors**

If one of the above conditions doesn't hold, then you need to deal with collectors, which have different tradeoffs.

Collectors work in parallel by operating on intermediate results in a thread-confined manner. The intermediate results are then merged into the final result. There are two operations to consider: 1) the accumulation of individual elements into the intermediate results, and 2) the merging (or combining) of the intermediate results into a final result.

Between `LinkedList` and `ArrayList`, it's likely that `ArrayList` is faster, but you should probably benchmark this to be sure. Note that `Collectors.toList` uses `ArrayList` by default, although this may change in a future release.

**LinkedList**

Each element being accumulated (`LinkedList.add`) involves allocating a new list node and hooking it to the end of the list. Hooking the node to the list is quite fast, but this involves an allocation for every single stream element, which will probably incur minor garbage collections as accumulation proceeds.

Merging (`LinkedList.addAll`) is also quite expensive. The first step is to convert the source list to an array; this is done by looping over every node of the list and storing the element into a temporary array. Then, the code iterates over this temporary array and adds each element to the end of the destination list. This incurs allocation of a new node for each element, as noted above. Thus a merge operation is quite expensive, because it iterates over every element in the source list *twice* and incurs allocation for each element, which probably introduces garbage collection overhead.

**ArrayList**

Accumulation of each element usually involves appending it to the end of the array contained within the `ArrayList`. This is usually quite fast, but if the array is full, it must be reallocated and copied into a larger array. The growth policy for `ArrayList` is to allocate the new array to be 50% larger than the current one, so reallocations occur proportional to the log of the number of elements being added, which isn't too bad. All the elements have to be copied over, however, which means that the earlier elements might need to be copied multiple times.

Merging an `ArrayList` is probably much cheaper than `LinkedList`. Converting an `ArrayList` to an array involves a bulk copy (not one-at-a-time) of the elements from the source into a temporary array. The destination array is resized if necessary (which is likely in this case), requiring a bulk copy of all the elements. The source elements are then bulk-copied from the temporary array to the destination, which has been pre-sized to accomodate them.

**Discussion**

Given the above, it seems like `ArrayList` will be faster than `LinkedList`. However, even collection to an `ArrayList` requires some unnecessary reallocation and copying of many elements, probably several times. A potential future optimization would be for `Collectors.toList` to accumulate elements into a data structure that's optimized for fast-append access, preferably one that's been pre-sized to accommodate the expected number of elements. A data structure that supports fast merging is a possibility as well.

If all you need to do is iterate over the final result, it shouldn't be too difficult to roll your own data structure that has these properties. Significant simplification should be possible if it doesn't need to be a full-blown List. It could accumulate into pre-sized lists to avoid reallocations, and merging would simply gather these into a tree structure or list-of-lists. See the JDK's [SpinedBuffer](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/jdk8-b132/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/SpinedBuffer.java) (a private implementation class) for ideas.

Comment: I suppose that making `Collectors.toList` use `SpinedBuffer` internally would be a simple change (it’s rather surprising that it doesn’t in current versions), however, preallocating lists with appropriate capacity is quite hard as the `Collector` API simply lacks a way of allowing the `Stream` to tell the `Collector` the desired capacity…

Comment: It seems like the `LinkedList` story would be much better if Java provided an internal way to concatenate two such lists in constant time. I wonder why they don't?

Comment: @BrandonMintern The `java.util.concurrent` package has `BlockingQueue.drainTo()` which seems to have the right semantics: elements are removed from the source and added to the destination in a single operation. `LinkedList` doesn't implement `BlockingQueue` though. Working on a data structure optimized for fast merging (such as `SpinedBuffer`) seems more promising.

Answer (score 4):

Given the cost of a context switch, and multithreading in general. The performance gains of switching between a type of list is generally *really* insignificant. Even if you use a suboptimal list - it won't matter.

<sup>If you *really* care, then `ArrayList` because of cache locality would *probably* do a better job, but it depends.</sup>

Comment: Your reluctant answer of "ArrayList" is right, but you're missing the more important part of the story.  Yes, locality matters, but that's mostly single-threaded thinking; in evaluating the scalability of parallel algorithms, you care a lot about how effectively the source can be recursively split.  ArrayList happens to excel here too, so your answer is right but mostly for the wrong reason.

Comment: What I meant by cache locality is that splitting an array into N bits for N threads allows keeping the array in cache for all N threads. My reluctant answer is irrelevant anyway because algorithms that are not cache oblivious do not look like this anyway - they're rarely written in Java (or any other language that doesn't let you specify memory layout) and they certainly don't use .parallelStream (which is awesome by the way - I love .prallelStream for dirt-easy parallelism)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, `ArrayList` is much more friendly to parallelization compared to `LinkedList` because arrays are easy to split into pieces to hand to each thread.

However, since your terminal operation is to write the result to a file, parallelization may not help you at all since you will likely be limited by IO, not by CPU.